# php get free space of a removable media (eg. USB Flash Drive)

Tags: php, removable-storage

Title says it all, I tried disk_free_space(), but it is not working for me. I guess it only returns "disk space" and not just any random media.

I have a script that would create another file in the removable drive, and a simple check for free space would definitely be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried `diskfreespace()` function? It returns the free space, in bytes, of the specified directory. This function is an alias of the disk_free_space() function.

Comment: If you're planning to put this script online, you will not be successful - PHP runs on server and even if `disk_free_space()` is not blocked by the admins, it will check for local server free space.

Comment: @DipakG. Thanks! that was what I was looking for. You might want to create an answer for it so I can upvote?

Comment: @Nordenheim Would have appreciated if you answered the question but thanks. It is for private use only. Server is a localhost.

Comment: @Aesreal I am glad! Just added my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `diskfreespace()` function. It returns the free space, in bytes, of the specified directory. This function is an alias of the disk_free_space() function.

Comment: by any chance do you know how to get the remaining size of the root partition of the removable media? diskfreespace("F:") works but i realised that it gives me the entire free space of the removable media instead of only the root partition. any ideas?